# SSH: Shrinking root partition

Tags: ssh, partition

I have a server accessible via SSH and it has a 3.6TB hard disk with one partition

I want to shrink `/` partition to 92GB and make a 8GB partition for `/tmp` and make another one (3.5TB) for `/home` but ... I don't know how to.

```
root@server4 [/etc]# parted /dev/sda unit s print
Model: HP LOGICAL VOLUME (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 7813971632s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start    End          Size         File system  Name  Flags
 1      2048s    514047s      512000s      ext2               boot
 2      514048s  7813969919s  7813455872s                     lvm


root@server4 [/etc]# lvs
  LV   VG   Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root vg   -wi-ao----  3.61t                                                   
  swap vg   -wi-ao---- 23.62g                                                   
  tmp  vg   -wi-ao----  1.00g
```

CentOS 6.7 x86_x64

Comment: Please run `parted /dev/sda unit s print` and update your question to include the output. You can delete the information about `fsck` as it's irrelevant.

Comment: Ah. It's LVM - that's really good news. Please include the output of `lvs`

Comment: @roaima `lvs` added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following information is taken from https://rbgeek.wordpress.com/2013/02/11/how-to-reduce-the-root-partition-in-lvm/ This is CentOS 6.3 but I don't see why it shouldn't also be applicable to 6.7.

1. Boot the CentOS installation DVD and choose the Rescue option
2. Skip options until you get to the point where you can start a shell. (Do not allow the system to attempt to mount the filesystems.)
3. Enable LVM in the rescue environment with the commands `vgscan` and `vgchange -a y`
4. Run `lvdisplay | grep Path` and confirm that the root partition you want to shrink is `/dev/vg/root`
5. Ensure the filesystem is clean by running `fsck -f /dev/vg/root`. If you get a warning that the filesystem is mounted then STOP IMMEDIATELY and DO NOT PROCEED.
6. Resize the `root` filesystem to the desired size, `lvresize --resizefs --size 92G /dev/vg/root`. This may re-run `fsck`; that's fine.

At this point you should now have enough space in your LVM partition to extend and create the new filesystems

1. Resize the `tmp` partition into the newly available space, `lvresize --size 8G /dev/vg/tmp` and extend the filesystem `fsck -f /dev/root/tmp; resize2fs /dev/root/tmp`
2. Create the `home` filesystem. I'd recommend you initially create it as 1T rather than the full disk as it's very easy to increase the size of a filesystem and partition later. Run `lvcreate --name home --size 1T /dev/vg`
3. Create the filesystem on the new filesystem `mkfs -t ext3 -L home /dev/vg/home`. If you have `ext4` available to you use that instead of `ext3` for the filesystem type
4. Exit the rescue shell and restart your system

Log on and mount the new `home` filesystem on `/mnt/home`

```
mkdir /mnt/home
mount /dev/vg/home /mnt/home
```

Move all the data from /home to /mnt/home

```
mv /home/* /mnt/home
```

Edit `/etc/fstab` and create a new entry for `/home`. Remember to use `ext4` instead of `ext3` if that's how you created the filesystem earlier

```
LABEL=home /home ext3 defaults 0 2
```

Umount the new home directory filesystem and remount it where it belongs

```
umount /mnt/home
mount /home
```

Reboot once more for good measure. At the very least, log out, but I'd recommend a full restart.

Comment: I only have SSH access ... what should I do with no DVD ?

Comment: You need to boot from something other than your current live root partition as you cannot shrink a live partition. If it's a VPS there may be an "emergency boot" option from the control panel, or you may need to contact the support line and ask them to shrink the partition for you.